# Updating with multiple variables with MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have 2 variables that contain a a string of text. I need to update them in the table, but out of the 20 + different variations of about 5 different scripts that I've tried out, it just doesn't update!

I can update using this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET quantity = $q WHERE sessionid='" .session_id(). "' AND description = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**but** I am now working on a different page, where I need a slightly different update query. Which is:

```
UPDATE cart SET quantity = $q WHERE sessionid = $somethin AND description = $desc
```

And for that I have:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET quantity = $q WHERE sessionid = $o AND description = $d") or die(mysql_error());
```

(I have tried many variations with different quotes in different places for the above query, but nothing works!)

I have also tried:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("my01..com", "dbase", "2354ret345ert");
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'UPDATE cart
        SET quantity="'.$q.'"
        WHERE sessionid="$o" AND description = "$d"';

mysql_select_db('mysql_94569_dbase');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

That last one doesn't display any errors, in fact, it even tells me that it has successfully updated! But it's lying. It hasn't updated anything.

Can someone please help me out here, I am really getting sick of reading tutorial after turorial and never learning anything because they all have differnt syntax and none of it seems to work.

What I would like to do is:

```
UPDATE table SET columnname = $this WHERE thiscolumn = $this AND thiscolumn = $that

$this = $var
```

Thank you

Comment: try echo $sql; so we can see ur sql input...(maybe the problem isnt in that query but in the vars like $d,$o...etc...)

Comment: Thank you, here it is: **Updated data successfully UPDATE cart SET quantity="4545455" WHERE sessionid="$o" AND description = "$d"1 x 19 x 3.2 Wire Rope 1 Roll Stainless GR316 Unit Price4545455 **   But it still didn't update. And that whole thing is a mess, *4545455* is a quantity and shouldn't be at the end like that

Comment: @Lucifer, your echoed thing has `"$o"` and `"$d"` in it. That means the variables $o is not correctly populated. That's why your query is failing.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the quotes in description and SessionID, do it like this:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE cart
              SET quantity = '".$q."'
              WHERE sessionid = '".$o."' AND description = '".$d."'");
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that one too. No errors or anything, just doesn't update. I even pasted your code, and tried it again. Still no go. :S

Answer (score 0):

In order to save you confusion, I would recommend start using concatenation operator (eg 'UPDATE '.$table .' SET ...')instead of writing variables directly to strings (eg. "UPDATE $table SET ...").
in this case your query would look like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET quantity = ".$q." WHERE sessionid='" .session_id(). "' AND description = '".$d."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

This might help you to find problems with quotes and parenthesis quicker

Comment: That's the one I already had working. I don't need the session_id() one anymore as I said in the question. I am having problems with the other one: $o

Comment: well, change the session_id() to $o.  The point of this answer was to say that you should use concatenation if you are having problems with parenthesis in the string.

Answer (score 0):

BAD:
I had this query in php:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET username = ".$nume." WHERE id = ".$userID;
```

That did this SQL:

```
UPDATE users SET username = elev WHERE id = 2
```

GOOD: For it to work I changed it to this php:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET username = ".'"'.$nume.'"'." WHERE id = ".$userID;
```

That did this SQL:

```
UPDATE users SET username = "elev" WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: you should not put in your values by concat'ing strings. Use placeholders (?) and bind variables, to prevent SQL-injections. Even with trusted variables. It's a good practise.